How to implement a custom loss function (NCD) in pytorch?
I would like to implement a custom loss function known as Normalised Compression Distance or more commonly NCD for short. I am not quite sure how to approach this.
Could someone explain and give an example of how one would implement this in python for pytorch?
Here is the mathematical description:
Ncd link
I have implemented it as described, however I am not able to run a backwards pass over it as it has not been designed with torch implemented math.
def loss_fn(self, x, y):
    xy = len(gzip.compress(np.concatenate(x.detach().numpy(),y.detach().numpy())))
    x = len(gzip.compress(x.detach().numpy()))
    y = len(gzip.compress(y.detach().numpy()))

    loss = (xy - min(x,y))/ (max(x,y))
    print(loss)
    return torch.tensor(loss)

Update:
Here is how the code looks now:
def loss_fn(self, x, y):
    xy = len(gzip.compress(str(torch.cat((x,y))).encode('utf-8')))
    x = len(gzip.compress(str(x).encode('utf-8')))
    y = len(gzip.compress(str(y).encode('utf-8')))

    loss = (xy - torch.min(torch.tensor([x,y])))/ (torch.max(torch.tensor([x,y]))
    print(loss)

    return torch.tensor(loss)

I get the following error when running the loss.backwards on the output of the loss function:
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
I solved the error above by using requires_grad=True in my tensors.

then just design it with torch implemented math.... e.g. use torch.min instead of min etc. That is why those functions exist.

Thank you. Do I have to implement the loss function as a module of nn and override specific methods for forwards and backwards to work? I need to be able to call loss.backwards.

No you don't. you can call backwards in a custom function, as long as the functions inside are torch differenciable. Just make your function take tensors, return tensors, and use torch functions inside, that is the only thing you need.

Would it be possible to give me an example of how to implement it? Is what I have updated differentiable?

The issue you are going to run into is: because the compression function Z is not implemented in Torch, you can not rely on Torch's autograd methods to calculate the gradients.
This will leave you having to implement the forward and backward methods on your own.  For the backward method, you will need to derive a gradient function, which is probably not possible in a closed form solution for compression algorithms like LZA, LZ1, LZ2, etc.
This leaves computing the gradient numerically using the definition of the derivative: f(x+δ) - f(x-δ) / 2δ, where δ is small.
Pytorch has an example of implementing a custom loss function with it's own gradient (no numerically computed) here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html
This is an example of implementing a custom loss function with calls to functions/methods outside of Pytorch that has a numerically calculated gradient.  Keep in mind, this is a very rudimentary implementation with a simple for-loop, there are probably better/faster implementations.
def normalized_compressive_dist(x: torch.Tensor, y: torch.Tensor):
    xy = len(gzip.compress(np.concatenate([
        x.detach().numpy().ravel(), 
        y.detach().numpy().ravel()
    ])))
    x = len(gzip.compress(x.detach().numpy().ravel()))
    y = len(gzip.compress(y.detach().numpy().ravel()))

    loss = (xy - min(x,y))/ (max(x,y))
    return torch.tensor(loss)


class NCDLoss(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x_input, y_input):
        ctx.save_for_backward(x_input, y_input)
        loss = normalized_compressive_dist(x_input, y_input)
        return loss

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        x_input, y_input= ctx.saved_tensors
        delta = 1e-5
        grad_input = torch.zeros_like(y_input)

        # compute perturbation for each element in the tensor
        for i in range(x_input.numel()):
            input_flat = x_input.view(-1)
            original_value = input_flat[i]

            # compute f(x + delta), f(x - delta)
            input_flat[i] = original_value + delta
            loss_plus = normalized_compressive_dist(input_flat.view_as(x_input), y_input)
            input_flat[i] = original_value - delta
            loss_minus = normalized_compressive_dist(input_flat.view_as(x_input), y_input)

            # restore original value
            input_flat[i] = original_value
            grad_input.view(-1)[i] = (loss_plus - loss_minus) / (2 * delta)
        return grad_input * grad_output

